# Cannot create p2sh-p2wpkh/ (Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length'))

Tags: p2sh-p2wpkh

I'm trying to create transactions with external scripts. Separately, using each input separately and creating a transaction with one input, everything works out with all the scripts.

```js
import * as bitcoin from 'bitcoinjs-lib';
import * as ecc from 'tiny-secp256k1';
import { ECPairFactory } from 'ecpair';

const ECPair = ECPairFactory(ecc);

const network = bitcoin.networks.testnet;

function addP2pkhInput(psbt, tx) {
    psbt.addInput({
        hash: tx.hash,
        index: tx.index,
        nonWitnessUtxo: Buffer.from(tx.nonWitnessUtxo, 'hex')
    });
}

function addP2wpkhInput(psbt, tx) {
    psbt.addInput({
        hash: tx.hash,
        index: tx.index,
        witnessUtxo: {
            script: tx.witnessUtxo.script,
            value: tx.value,
        }
    });
}

function addP2shP2wpkhInput(psbt, tx, network, pubkey) {
    const payment = bitcoin.payments.p2sh({
        redeem: bitcoin.payments.p2wpkh({
                pubkey,
                network
            }
        ),
        network
    });

    psbt.addInput({
        hash: tx.hash,
        index: tx.index,
        redeemScript: payment.redeem.output,
        witnessUtxo: {
            script: payment.output,
            value: tx.value,
        }
    });
}

const toXOnly = pubKey => (pubKey.length === 32 ? pubKey : pubKey.slice(1, 33));

function addP2trInput(psbt, inputIndex, tx, network, pubkey) {
    const { output } = bitcoin.payments.p2tr({
        internalPubkey: toXOnly(pubkey),
        network
    });

    psbt.addInput({
        hash: tx.hash,
        index: inputIndex,
        witnessUtxo: {
            script: output,
            value: tx.value, 
        },
        tapInternalKey: toXOnly(pubkey),
    });
}

const psbt = new bitcoin.Psbt({ network });

let totalAmount = 0;

const keyPairs = [
    ECPair.fromWIF('cVgXWJcMy82StLBxuSv7GBTGoLy7voaqMgtPtv7vjQsooMuBWGrH', network),
    ECPair.fromWIF('cVFHShSXiPNp7txS5pcwszm2iQT2tX1wKsXy5a4i1f9PHn1fH6MU', network),
    ECPair.fromWIF('cUpqvCmmnSKt2iAMyzVtADyecsSQiZLkvKojidbpneu8GKt4GHFG', network),
    ECPair.fromWIF('cP2ujbEBrMUf8EiunVx4CX662j8W13SMPVveezR1dR2yKXE6jE35', network).tweak(
        bitcoin.crypto.taggedHash('TapTweak', toXOnly(ECPair.fromWIF('cP2ujbEBrMUf8EiunVx4CX662j8W13SMPVveezR1dR2yKXE6jE35', network).publicKey)),
    )
];

const tx1 = {
    hash: "3399dfd038762c7f37d45a2db55568101b350472099e9a7b640aa917174c7e11",
    index: 0,
    value: 1155399,
    nonWitnessUtxo: "0200000001e02bdcc56cdf90e71299f697c4fca0e968a8e1d415b58f947d2337754cc18046000000006b483045022100995eab8d8d13a500b768d866c84636840de85a4880f6d49157b3fb424bc7c846022052dcf9bac0f12aa28e0c862c753ae4e0dc7dab023da6d4fd9c4033382935e1740121026ed517acfe148b1d012af4f99134fa24582e4018dfbfe7df1b1b748e2ee7a83bffffffff0147a11100000000001976a9145b63c66657bf13babcbfa9425fb39cdbd28d38de88ac00000000"
}

const tx2 = {
    hash: "91305d2e311c4c2eb4eaee825abd4c6da91b71b0f1a98124fea116b5835283d1",
    index: 0,
    value: 1284858,
    witnessUtxo: {
        script: bitcoin.address.toOutputScript('tb1qs3hcrf2ls2cgsh0xvnlnsk546flrkugpaseuwf', network)
    }
}

const tx3 = {
    hash: "4db77e68c7cbf9a5b10f2d9e8c9ca0a9c5612abb9f9d2a62e72bb5f2d5a9dc26",
    index: 0,
    value: 1265769
}

const tx4 = {
    hash: "138f2d616c36cf86c2500f308de198c7ce99ed3b0b1626f454caffb1bd266374",
    index: 0,
    value: 50000
}

addP2pkhInput(psbt, tx1, network);
addP2wpkhInput(psbt, tx2, network);
addP2shP2wpkhInput(psbt, tx3, network, keyPairs[2].publicKey);
addP2trInput(psbt, tx4, network);

totalAmount += tx1.value;
totalAmount += tx2.value;
totalAmount += tx3.value;
totalAmount += tx4.value;

psbt.addOutput({
    address: 'mggZoTM2Qb2Zdw4ADspJM51Tj8hzPuzKb4',
    value: totalAmount - 1000,
});

for (let i = 0; i < keyPairs.length; ++i) {
    psbt.signInput(i, keyPairs[i]);
}

psbt.finalizeAllInputs();

console.log(psbt.extractTransaction().toHex());
```

Comment: You forgot to add the input index and public key as an argument when invoking addP2trInput. When toXOnly is called from addP2trInput, the public key is undefined and '.length' can not be accessed